# why I can't use the pointer in place of index in an array to return the value and express the position of index?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, indexing, cs50

This is my code, where I am trying to arrange given numbers in an array into an ascending order with the help of pointers instead of indices. I kept trying to use pointer for expressing variables and position but I am having error code all the time, why I can't use the pointer in place of index?
And my second question is instead of changing the values , I was also thinking of switching the memory address inside the two pointers, can I do it?, if then how?

`````
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
void Ascending_Swap();
int main()
{ 
    int num[5];
     int *p = &num[0];
 for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
 {
     *(p+i) = get_int("Enter Number%i: ", i+1);
 }
for(int i = 1; i<5; i++)
 {
     //for(int x = i; x>0 && *p>*(p+x) ; x-- ) //Here *p remains constant ,yo sadhai num[0] nai rahanxa 
     for(int x = i; x>0 && *((p+x)-1)>*(p+x); x-- )
     {
     Ascending_Swap(*(p+x-1), *(p+x));
     }
 }
 for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
 {
     printf("%i\n",*(p+i));
 }
} 
void Ascending_Swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int T = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = T;
}````
`````

Comment: Don't make us to guess the error, please consider adding the error message instead.

Comment: Aside: `*(p+x)` is more naturally written as `p[x]`. Your code is hard enough to read as it is.

Comment: THe `Ascending_Swap()` function prototype has no parameters declared. Here -> `Ascending_Swap(*(p+x-1), *(p+x));` You're supposed to pass 2 pointers as parameters, but you pass 2 int values instead of pointers.

Comment: @pacfarlane yeah it is more easy to visualize the array with indices, but I wanted to do with pointer.